# Updating/rearranging portion of varchar value in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, replace

I have a varchar column called "*welcomeemailattachment*" where I store the path to a file that is used as an attachment on an email.  I need to update the values to a different path.

```
Change this:   /files/1089/attachment.pdf
To this:  /companies/1089/files/attachment.pdf
```

Where **attachment.pdf** can be any file name and **1089** can be any number.  This number is actually the company id.

I realize I could use replace to partially solve this problem like so:

```
UPDATE companies SET welcomeemailattachment = REPLACE(welcomeemailattachment, '/files/', '/companies/') WHERE field LIKE '/files/%';
```

but how do I insert the "**/files/**" part in between the companyid and the name of the file?

Comment: Use `SUBSTRING_INDEX` (see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index)

Comment: Why was my question down voted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7adba/2)

```
UPDATE companies SET welcomeemailattachment = CONCAT('/companies/',
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(welcomeemailattachment,'/',3),'/',-1),
'/files/',
SUBSTRING_INDEX(welcomeemailattachment,'/',-1))
```